# bootstrap 4 get text floating around image

Tags: image, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the text floating around the image and have done my research and found out this question has asked before, however, I did tried their code and still doesn't work. I have pasted my code down below and can anyone have a look and give me some suggestions. Is the grid system stop the text wrapper around image as it divided them into two separate sections. How can I make the text floating around the image like the photo.

```
<div class="container text-section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='float-left col-md-4'>
            <img src="./assets/img/img6.jpeg" alt="img" width='100%'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-8'>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                Aenean massa.
                Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
                ultricies nec,
                pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
                fringilla vel,
                aliquet nec,
                vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam
                dictum felis
                eu pede
                mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean
                vulputate eleifend
                tellus.
                Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
                dapibus in,
                viverra quis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
                eget dolor.
                Aenean massa.
                Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
                ultricies nec,
                pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
                fringilla vel,
                aliquet nec,
                feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: provide photo of your need and explain in brief what you want from our side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using rows and cols you wont get any floating as the columns always set a width.

Get rid of the cols and bring the image and the text together like this (i inserted a dummy image so you can actually see stuff):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container text-section">
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200" alt="img"> 
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                Aenean massa.
                Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
                ultricies nec,
                pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
                fringilla vel,
                aliquet nec,
                vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam
                dictum felis
                eu pede
                mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean
                vulputate eleifend
                tellus.
                Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
                dapibus in,
                viverra quis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
                eget dolor.
                Aenean massa.
                Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
                ultricies nec,
                pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
                fringilla vel,
                aliquet nec,
                feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                Aenean massa.
                Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
  </p>
</div>
```